# Is is posible to sample a database

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to sample any SQL database?

By sampling I means the database table should remain and retaining the foreign key constraints.
But the actual rows from the table should be reduced.If I have 1 million records in some of my tables then in the sample database I only want any 100 records.
I am doing some analysis and processing all records takes many days.

Comment: Rule of thumb - stats become meaningful when the sample is the square root of the population. More importantly, why does "processing all records takes many days"? This does not make  much sense. What are you trying to do? Show us your database tables, your queries and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, you can append the `SAMPLE` clause to your selects:

[image]

For example:

```
select * from table sample(20);
```

[sample_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2065953)

> The sample_clause lets you instruct the database to select from a
>   random sample of data from the table, rather than from the entire
>   table.
>
> **BLOCK**
>   BLOCK instructs the database to attempt to perform random block
>   sampling instead of random row sampling.
>
> Block sampling is possible only during full table scans or index fast
>   full scans. If a more efficient execution path exists, then Oracle
>   Database does not perform block sampling. If you want to guarantee
>   block sampling for a particular table or index, then use the FULL or
>   INDEX_FFS hint.
>
> **sample_percent**
>   For sample_percent, specify the percentage of the
>   total row or block count to be included in the sample. The value must
>   be in the range .000001 to, but not including, 100. This percentage
>   indicates the probability of each row, or each cluster of rows in the
>   case of block sampling, being selected as part of the sample. It does
>   not mean that the database will retrieve exactly sample_percent of the
>   rows of table.
>
> ...

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand it correctly that you have a production database with 1mil++ rows in some tables and you want to reduce the amount of rows in your test/development database?

This is pretty tricky and there is no feature which does this "in a few clicks".

First of all you should analyze the relations between the tables. If you have 100 tables with a small number of rows you can just leave them as they are. Just focus on the big tables and all other tables which reference these big tables.

For example:

- table CUSTOMER has 1mil rows which should be reduced to 10,000 rows
- table INVOICE references table CUSTOMER on column cust_id

In this scenario you have three (or even more) options:

- make sure that the foreign key is set to `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE SET NULL`. Now you can just delete rows from CUSTOMER without hurting the FK constraint.
- you can delete rows first from INVOICE and then from CUSTOMER
- During export/import using expdp/impdp you can specify a `WHERE` clause to reduce the data which is being exported. But this means that you might have to export each table in a single export command to make sure you correctly filter the data.

Like I said, it's tricky and you have to script the process yourself. But once you did that one time you can use it for the next refresh of the test/dev database.